# Combine two line of codes in one function with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm using `Cycle slideshow` and `setTimeout()` to give it seconds of delay

I want to to combine these two line of codes below to execute them simultaneously. But, I don't know how to accomplish this in JavaScript.

```
$('#slideshow').cycle('resume');
$('#slideshow').cycle({
                        sync:  false,
                        speed: 300,
                     })
```

I want to put them in one line like this:

```
$('#slideshow').cycle(??????///here is your help////??????");
```

If I don't do this, the slide show, again, starts from the initial point and I don't want it.

How may I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without looking in detail at the plugin's source code, I think from your description, that the plugin automatically starts from beginning whenever you set its options. That seems reasonable, as the plugin likely has to recalculate things from scratch whenever its options are changed.

Can you set the options once, e.g. during initialization, halting it then if necessary:

```
$('#slideshow').cycle({sync:false, speed:300}).cycle('pause');
```

Later, when you want to start the show, just resume it

```
$('#slideshow').cycle('resume');
```

Alternatively, you could look into setting the global options before initializing the slideshows.

Comment: I think you are completely right . but I want to continue it with other options (for few seconds more) , after resuming . you think it's not possible with this plugin?

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html

Comment: There may be a way to do what you want, but after skimming the plugin's source code I couldn't see an easy way to do it. It might be possible to intercept the prev/next events in your own code and keep track of which slide is currently showing. Then, when you want to resume the show, explicitly set the starting slide to whichever was showing last. Seems rather complicated, though.

Comment: you suggested a nice way .i think it will work . thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('#slideshow').cycle('resume').cycle({sync:  false,speed:300,});
```

Comment: that won't behave any differently that the OP's code. Although it's one line, it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: what about resume? i need it

Comment: it's concatenate the resume if you seen @Nima